# Rails updating has_many with nested fields loads duplicate each time in edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, nested-forms, has-many

In my edit

```
 <h3>Attach Project Images </h3>
                <%= f.fields_for :images do |pi| %>

                <h4>
                    <%= pi.label :attachment %>

                    <%= pi.file_field :attachment %>
                </h4>
                <%end%>

                <%= f.fields_for :images do |pi| %>
                <h4>
                    <%= pi.label :attachment %>

                    <%= pi.file_field :attachment %>
                </h4>
                <%end%>

                <%= f.fields_for :images do |pi| %>
                <h4>
                    <%= pi.label :attachment %>

                    <%= pi.file_field :attachment %>
                </h4>
                <%end%>
```

In controller,

```
def edit

    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
   # @project.images.cache!
    @project.images.build

  end
```

It shows 12 attachment fields initially in edit page if the project has 3 images. (It should only show 3 attachment fields).
I've been researching this for long now but couldn't come up with any working solutions.
Any help would be admired!
Cheers

Comment: can you confirm that `@project.images` is empty before the build?

Comment: @sundayAdefila even if I comment out the build it will show me 12 fields :( So I'm guessing it's not the build that cause me all these problems. For a fact I'm guessing that fields_for section is trying to duplicate things...

Comment: My guess is that the particular project already has some images associated with it.

Comment: It does. So the project has ONLY 3 images. when I try to edit the projects it shows me 12 fields. but it should only show me 3 fileds

Comment: Hmm... okay, so the project has 3 images, and then you added a `.build` making 4 images, and you have a `<%= f.fields_for :images do |pi| %>` 3 times on the page... calculating this gives 3*4 which equals 12 fields. do you understand this?

Comment: Well then if I remove .build it should show me only 3 fields ya? But when I remove .build it still shows 12 fields. :(

Comment: if you remove `.build`, I expect it to show you 9 fields.

Comment: what about if you remove 2 of your `%= f.fields_for :images do |pi| %>` and leave only one, and use that to debug it? also, try and delete all images associated with that project, and start again from there. I'm sure it will become more clear.

Comment: Aaah you'r a genies... I'm getting your point now.... It does show 9 fields :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @sundayAdefila I have fixed the issues according to your comments. Cheers

Comment: So I managed to solve that problem but now the images are not getting updated at all. :(